# How to set Content-type and MIME-Version headers in GmailApp.sendmail?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-apps

How can I set a custom Content-type and MIME-Version headers in GmailApp.sendmail in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the GmailApp won't give you that kind of capabilities, it's their infrastructure and they want to have some control of what flows through, and rely on automated methods of determining that.

On the other hand Custom Content Type can we set for attachment using the [GmailAttachment.SetContentType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment) method.

Cheers

Comment: that's unfortunate :( I don't think allowing setting of the Content-type and MIME-Version will have security implications for Google.....